# Cant bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' error even after importing 'FormsModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im getting a weird error. I have added the following in my module:

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";


@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule]
})
```

**In my HTML file:**

```
 <div class="uk-margin" id="search-bar">
  <div class="uk-search uk-search-default">
    <span uk-search-icon></span>
    <input class="uk-search-input" type="search" [(ngModel)]="filterKeyword" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
</div>
```

**I get the following errors:**

[image]

I am not using `form` within my code as it doesn't need one. I just have a `input` field that requires 2 way binding with `ngModel`

Comment: Do you have **only** `AppModule` or do you have other (custom) modules as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have other custom (feature) modules as well. I only imported `FormsModule` within the `custom` modules that need to use it.

Comment: have you enclosed the <input> inside <form></form> ?

Comment: Works fine for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnerfa?file=app/app.component.html (see `app/app.component.html`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thats weird it won't work for me. Does it matter if I'm importing both `reactive and forms` module?

Comment: Should be easy to find out.